# How to identify the number of common character between two strings?

Tags: java, for-loop

> Given 2 strings, str1 and str2, as input, return the count of the chars which are in the same position in str1 and str2.

## Sample Input #1

count("New York","New Delhi")

## Sample Output #1

4

Because the two strings share the same four leading characters: "New "

## Sample Input #2

count("rhinoceroses","hippopotamus")

## Sample Output #2

2

Because 'o' occupies the fourth position and 's' the eleventh position in both strings.

**MyApproach**

@Edit

```
public int count(String str1, String str2)
{
    int p=0;
    int k=0;
    int count=0;
    int l1=str1.length();
    int l2=str2.length();
    if(l1>=l2)
    {
     while(k<l2)
     {
         char ch1=str1.charAt(p);
         char ch2=str2.charAt(k);
    
            if(ch1==ch2)
            {
                p++;
                k++;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                p++;
                k++;
                
            }
      }         
     }
     else
     {
         char ch1=str1.charAt(p);
         char ch2=str2.charAt(k);
    
         while(k<l1)
         {
             
            if(ch1==ch2)
            {
                p++;
                k++;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                p++;
                k++;
                
            }
          }         
      }
   return count;
}
```

Parameters            Actual Output Expected Output

'Trisect''Classes'    0             1

> I am getting correct output now.

Thanku

Comment: Waaaaaaaaay too many loops.  The answer is much simpler.  Try to think it out some more.

Comment: Your post currently reads like a homework dump. You've posted a bunch of requirements and some code, but haven't explained what the problem with the code is or even asked a question. Your question does not mean the standards we expect on Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Tip: You only need 1 loop which goes to the smallest length string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public int count(String str1, String str2) {
    int result = 0;
    if (str1.length() == 0 || str2.length() == 0)
        return result;
    if (str1.length() > str2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
            if (str2.charAt(i) == str1.charAt(i))
                result++;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(i))
                result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @YassinHajaj Any better solution you can share ? Thanks

Comment: I answered especially for you. You can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done more preciously using a single loop. Find the below code with the solution :-

```
class GetCount {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String myString = "rhinoceroses";
    String myString1 = "hippopotamus";

    count(myString, myString1);
}

/**
 * @param myString
 * @param myString1
 */
private static void count(String myString, String myString1) {
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int length = myString.length() < myString1.length() ? myString.length() : myString1.length();
    while(i < length) {
        if(myString.charAt(i) == myString1.charAt(i)) {
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Count is :: " + count);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a compact solution, very easy to understand.

---

### Solution

```
public static int count(String s1, String s2){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < (s1.length() > s2.length() ? s2 : s1).length() ; i++){
        count += s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

### Input

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
            "New York, New Delhi : " 
            + count("New York", "New Delhi"));

    System.out.println(
            "Rhinoceroses, Hippopotamus : " 
            + count ("Rhinoceroses", "Hippopotamus"));
}
```

---

### Output

```
New York, New Delhi : 4
Rhinoceroses, Hippopotamus : 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided before are useless, as they work only if the characters are in the same sequence.
**Here is my solution:**

```
private int commonCharacterCount(String s1, String s2) {
    int counter = 0;

    List<Character> list = new LinkedList<>();
    for (char aChar : s1.toCharArray()) {
        list.add(aChar);
    }

    for (char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
        if (list.contains(c)) {
            list.remove(Character.valueOf(c));
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this. (Try it) -

```
public int count(String s1, String s2) {
    int result=0;
    char[] ch1=s1.toCharArray();
    char[] ch2=s2.toCharArray();

    if(ch1.length>ch2.length){
    for(int i=0;i<ch2.length;i++){
        if(ch1[i]==ch2[i]){
            result++;
        }
    }
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0;i<ch1.length;i++){
            if(ch2[i]==ch1[i]){
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript solution. Guaranteed constraints:
1 ≤ s1.length ≤ 15, 1 ≤ s2.length ≤ 15

```
function commonCharacterCount(s1: string, s2: string): number {
    let count = 0;
    let s_1 = s1.split("");
    let s_2 = s2.split("");

    for (let i = 0; i < s_1.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < s_2.length; j++) {
            if (s_1[i] == s_2[j]) {
                count++;
                s_2.splice(j, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to count of the chars which are in the same position we can do it in a single loop checking at each iteration (string position) if the chars are equal or not. And the number of iteration should be the minimum length of `str1` and `str2` (maybe we could extract `Math.min(str1.length(), str2.length())` in a variable). I compressed the `if - else` branches from your solution to a single loop using the minimum string length in loop condition.

```
public int countCommonChars(String str1, String str2) {
  int commonCharsNumber = 0;
  for(int i=0; i< Math.min(str1.length(), str2.length()); i++) {
    if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(i)) {
      commonCharsNumber++;
    }
  }
  return commonCharsNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int commonCharacterCount(String s1, String s2) {

    Map<String, Integer> mapOfString1 = getOcuurances(s1);
    Map<String, Integer> mapOfString2 = getOcuurances(s2);

    int counter = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : mapOfString2.entrySet()) {
        if (mapOfString1.get(entry.getKey()) != null) {
            if (mapOfString1.get(entry.getKey()) > entry.getValue()) {
                counter += entry.getValue();
            } else {
                counter += mapOfString1.get(entry.getKey());
            }
        }

    }
    return counter;
}

public Map<String, Integer> getOcuurances(String s) {
    Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] strings = s.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if (hashMap.containsKey(strings[i])) {
            hashMap.put(strings[i], hashMap.get(strings[i]) + 1);
        } else {
            hashMap.put(strings[i], 1);
        }
    }
    return hashMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count(String s1, String s2) {
    Map<Character, Integer> charCountMap1 = getCharacterCount(s1);
    Map<Character, Integer> charCountMap2 = getCharacterCount(s2);

    return charCountMap1.entrySet().stream().map(charCountEntry ->
        Math.min(charCountEntry.getValue(), charCountMap2.getOrDefault(charCountEntry.getKey(), 0))
    ).collect(Collectors.summingInt(value -> value));
}

private Map<Character, Integer> getCharacterCount(String str) {
    Map<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.toCharArray().length; i++) {
        Integer count = charCountMap.getOrDefault(str.charAt(i), 0);
        charCountMap.put(str.charAt(i), ++count);
    }
    return charCountMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to go with below:-

```
    private static int solution(String s1, String s2) {

    int count = 0;

    List<Character> listChars = s1.chars().mapToObj(chr -> (char) chr)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));

    for (char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
        if (listChars.contains(c)) {
            listChars.remove(Character.valueOf(c));
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Though there is already an accepted answer but I don't feel that answer is concise enough, hence I am giving mine (haven't compiled, treat it as psuedo-code please)

```
public static int count(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1 == null || s2==null ||s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    int minLength = Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length());
    int count = 0;
    for (int i < 0; i < minLength; ++i) {
        if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i)) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```